# A rake task by .rake file

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I have the following Rakefile in a Ruby 1.9.3 project:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'json'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb"
  t.verbose = true
end

task :default => :test

namespace :omglol do
  namespace :file_a do
    task :foo do
      # do some stuff
    end
  end

  namespace :file_b do
    task :bar do
      # do some stuff
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, the first part of this file allow to run tests, just using `rake` command. And the second part contains some tasks.

Actually, I have a lot of tasks inside omglol:file_a and omglol:file_b namespaces. That's why I would like to move each of them inside a file, for instance `tasks/omglol/file_a.rake` and `tasks/omglol/file_b.rake`.

Is there a best way to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Simply move the logic into the appropriate files and then `require` them.

Example Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'json'
require 'lib/tasks/omglol/file_a.rake' # <= contains your subtasks

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb"
  t.verbose = true
end

task :default => :test
```

Then in `lib/tasks/omglol/file_a.rake` simply define your tasks as normal:

```
namespace :omglol do
  namespace :file_a do
    task :foo do
      # do some stuff
    end
  end
end
```

The pattern would be the same for file_b.rake.